# How do I import a full package but still call specific methods from a package directly?

Tags: python

I'm trying to both a module and an import from a module.

I've been using `from time import sleep` for a few years now, but I'm wanting access to more of the features from the package.

My issue is if I use `import time` I lose the ability call `sleep()` directly.

I've tried;

```
import time
from time import sleep
```

But I get the error:

```
    loop_time = time()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

and if I try importing the whole package and remove `from time import sleep` I get the error:

```
    sleep(1)
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined
```

I can use the rename all function within visual studio to update `sleep(x)` to `time.sleep(x)` but I was wondering there is a different way/better way to do this? I don't have a large issue because I don't use the word sleep anywhere in my code but I expect if there was a word I couldn't rename all with this would be a much more annoying issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `*` keyword.

```py
from time import *
```

But beware, it is generally bad practice as you might get some naming clashes, and using `time.sleep()` makes it clear to whoever reading the code which module you are using.

Comment: With that in mind I updated the `sleep()` calls to `time.sleep()` and I'm using `import time` however, oddly getting a TypeError when trying to use `time()` time now isn't giving me the time.

Comment: Had to use `time.time()` shockingly

Comment: You should be able to use this answer and use `sleep()` directly without the `time.` . I think the error you're getting is becuase if you try to import a module called x with `import x` and then in your code call `x()` that wouldn't make much sense, right? However, some modules like datetime have classes called datetime, so something like `from datetime import datetime` and then call `datetime()` in your code would actually work just fine.